# Как сменить статус заявки через SetPropertyValuesEx?

Tags: php, битрикс

```
$externalId = $arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'];  // id заявки текущей
$arValues['STATUS']['XML_ID'] = 41792862;  // симв. код статуса 500
$arCurrentStatus['ID'] = 500; // текущий  500


CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array( $arValues['STATUS']['XML_ID'] =>  $arCurrentStatus['ID']));
```

Подскажите как мне правильно переписать SetPropertyValuesEx для смены статуса у заявки в битриксе по клику
Текущие данные : 
41792861 XML_ID
200  - id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array('STATUS' => 201)); // на исполнении
      // CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array('STATUS' => 408)); // дозапрос
     // CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array('STATUS' => 386468)); // отказ
     // CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($arValues['EXTERNAL_ID'], false, array('STATUS' => 408)); // дозапрос
```

вот так срабатывает , при перезагрузке страницы